# substitute constant to a formula matlab

Tags: matlab, substitution, symbolic-math

I define in MATLAB:

```
syms k2 k3;
k1 = k2/k3;
```

Where `k2` and `k3` are [symbolic variables](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html). Then typing `k1` gives the output:

```
k1 =

k2/k3
```

Assign constant value for `k2` and `k3`:

```
k2 = 1; k3 = 2;
```

Then I type in matlab commandline:

```
>> k1

k1 =

k2/k3
```

Is there any command which shows the result `k1 = 1/2 = 0.5` without using the `subs` function? In the case my formulas have a lot of variables, it is inconvenient to use `subs`.

Comment: What's wrong with `subs(k1)`? You don't need to provide the additional variables as arguments if they've already been set.

Comment: I'm curious why you accepted my answer and then unaccepted it days later, when there are no alternatives and it works?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `eval(k1)`

```
syms k2 k3;
k1 = k2/k3;

eval(k1) % output k1 = k2/k3

k2 = 1;

eval(k1) % output k1 = 1/k3

k3 = 2;

eval(k1) % output ans = 0.5

k1       % output k1 = k2/k3
```

Edit:
It's been pointed out in the comments that `subs` works in the same way (and may be preferable). From the `subs` [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html):

> subs(s) returns a copy of s replacing symbolic variables in s with their values obtained from the calling function and the MATLAB® workspace

So you can use `subs(k1)` in the same way as I've used `eval(k1)` above. It gives the same outputs for the first two examples, with the last example taking advantage of the result's exact fractional form as shown.

```
subs(k1) % ouput ans = 1/2
```

Comment: That's the documentation for wrong version of `eval`, it should be for `sym/eval`. However, Matlab doesn't seem to maintain documentation for `sym/eval` anymore (other than a minimal help file). This is most likely because `subs` should be used instead, i.e., just `subs(k1)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @horchler, I've edited my answer to reflect your input.

Comment: In the case I have many constants to replace, subs may be inconvenient due to replacing a long array. So I want to find a solution except 'subs'.

Comment: What do you mean "replacing a long array"?